# Problems with defining DataOutputStream and DataInputStream variables

Tags: java, networking

I'm having trouble using my out, in, and inUTF variables for some reason.
I've tried defining them in different places and using them in different ways and I can't seem to find a solution. Here's my code.

```
public class Server {

static ServerSocket serverSocket;
static Socket socket;
static DataOutputStream out;
static DataInputStream in;
static boolean running = false;

static int playerX;
static int playerY;
static int playerZ;

static String[] arrayX;
static String[] arrayY;
static String[] arrayZ;

static String inUTF;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    running = true;
    System.out.println("Starting server");
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7877);
    System.out.println("Finished");

    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    inUTF = in.readUTF();

    while (running) {
        tick();
    }

}

public static void tick() {
    try {

        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong in the tick() loop: Could not accept client connection");
        }

        if (inUTF.startsWith("X")) {
            arrayX = inUTF.split(":");
            playerX = Integer.parseInt(arrayX[1]);
            out.writeUTF("X:" + playerX);

        } else if (inUTF.startsWith("Y")) {
            arrayY = inUTF.split(":");
            playerY = Integer.parseInt(arrayY[1]);
            out.writeUTF("Y:" + playerY);

        } else if (inUTF.startsWith("Z")) {
            arrayZ = inUTF.split(":");
            playerZ = Integer.parseInt(arrayZ[1]);
            out.writeUTF("Z:" + playerZ);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong in the tick() loop: Did not receive a player position");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong in the tick() loop");
    }
}
```

Comment: `socket` has not been initialized, so this `socket.getOutputStream()` will fail

Comment: BTW I can not understand the logic you are wanting

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm pretty new to Java programming and I've been trying to find a solution for hours.

Comment: I'm making a multiplayer game and I'm just trying to send information from the server to the client.

Comment: If this is the `server` then you do not need a `Socket` just the `ServerSocket`

Comment: Well that explains a lot...

Comment: In your `main` you have this code    `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7877);` then you have this code `out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());` and this `in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` I think you forge to rename the `serverSocket` to `socket` or vise-versa.

Comment: The serverSocket doesn't let me do serverSocket.readUTF() and I need that for receiving the player position from the client.